# CSS !important - to set role for background

Tags: jquery, css

I am having an issue adding a class with Jquery to a div, thing here is that in the start the background blank but if I add the class "snapToGrid" id gives the class to the id #container but for some strange reason the class doesn't override all other things.

Is there any optimalization I can do here to improve my expected results?

Jquery:

```
$("#addSnapToGrid").on('click', function () {
        $("#fb-iframe").addClass('snapToGrid'); 
        });
```

CSS

```
  .snapToGrid {
background: url(../assets/img/grid20.gif) repeat !important;
}
```

Comment: You're attempting to add a background image to a facebook generated iFrame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it applying and ID in the top of the class, something like:

```
#fb-iframe.snapToGrid{
    background: url(../assets/img/grid20.gif) repeat !important;
}
```

That would overwrite the styles for `#fb-iframe`.

[Living Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/imac/KDEhD/)

And I would recommend to try to avoid important even  you are trying to overwrite inline styles.